# Java Oracle Jdbc parallel connections get terminates

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I created a java JDBC code with Oracle connectivity and created a Jar file.

Now I need to run the same Jar file for 18 times parallelly but when I trigger all the Jars only 3 or 4 jobs are running and others are getting terminated without even establishing the connection. I tried increasing the heap size as well but no use. can some please help me to fix this

I am getting "null pointer exception " and sometimes I am getting " out of memory " exception.
I am running my jar file as follows "`java -jar -Xmx5g javaconnection.jar`"

```
import java.sql.*;  
class OracleCon{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
//step1 load the driver class  
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

//step2 create  the connection object  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");  

//step3 create the statement object  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

//step4 execute query  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  

//step5 close the connection object  
con.close();  

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

}
```

Comment: You need to add the exceptions with full stack trace so we can understand the error.

Comment: Is this really the code that produces the NPEs and OOMEs?  I don't see how it is possible to get an NPE with this, and OOME would only be possible if the resultset has rows with monstrously large strings.  (And I don't see the point of running this code multiple times in parallel.)

Comment: this the error I am getting "Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread" . actually, we have  to run this code for 18 different tables at the same time so I am running the same Jar file just by passing table name as an argument by that time few jobs are getting terminated due to NEPs because of multiple connections to the database results in not connecting the db so when it comes to resultset if throws NEPs for only few jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This JVM option:

> Xmx5g

Will request a contiguous block of 5 GB of RAM from the operating system when your JVM starts. If you are running "java -jar -Xmx5g javaconnection.jar" 18 times, then the minimum amount of RAM your system needs is 5 GB x 18 = 90 GB of RAM. Your system probably doesn't have that much memory, so that's why you're running out of heap.

This program you've written shouldn't need 5 GB of RAM. Turn your heap space down.

Also, you probably don't want to parallelize this by manually running a jar 18 times. That's inefficient. You should look into using a database connection pool, like c3p0.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me and I could able to fix this now!